# Llamar una función desde jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un POST mediante jQuery, el cual si todo es correcto debe llamar una función, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, les dejo mi código por si alguien puede ayudarme.

```
function DesabilitarEstadoPlantilla(id, estado) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Inform/DesabilitarEstadoPlantilla/" + id,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",

            error: function (source) {
                alert("Error Carga Json");
            }
        });

        //Esta función quiero llamarla arriba.
        refrescartabla();
    }
```

Funciona casi correctamente, sucede que a veces no se realiza ese POST e igual llama a la función, y por eso necesito que si solo se ejecuta el jQuery, me ejecute la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `.done()` para ejecutar un código cuando tu llamada ajax se haya completado, algo así:

```
function DesabilitarEstadoPlantilla(id, estado) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Inform/DesabilitarEstadoPlantilla/" + id,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",

    error: function (source) {
      alert("Error Carga Json");
    },
  }).done(function () {
    refrescartabla();
  });
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias excelente tu respuesta. gracias